# How to exit a PhoneGap app?

Tags: android, cordova

I've seen this code being tossed around often whenever someone asks how to exit a PhoneGap app. However, it doesn't seem to work for me on v 2.0.0.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
          if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') === 'homePage') {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
            } else {
              window.history.back();
            }
        }, false);
```

Where am I supposed to put this bit of script? As of right now, I put it inside a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag on index.html. Is this snippet meant to go somewhere else?

Comment: i think homePage should be index.html

Answer (score 2):

That snippet of code will work just fine as long as the main div in your jQM app is called, "homepage". Just to make sure everything is setup correctly you should create a link like:

```
<a href="javascript:navigator.app.exitApp()">Exit</a>
```

in your index.html. Once you click it, the app should exit.

Comment: I see, I'll give this a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

code is correct, have you put the code in the method which is called on device ready?
see the following example,

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener only after phonegap is loaded completely
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
    //do anything
}
```